# Why does this pop-up window open blank?

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, radio-button, popup

I'm trying to set a web page to work. The page works but there is a thing I want to work from a pop-up. I want that people click there so a pop-up window opens and they can have access to its content. The pop-up window opens but the problem is it is not showing its content, it is blank.

Why is it showing blank?

I just want to check if it is the code first before trying to see if my browser is responsible. After all, if I want other people to use this feature, I must be sure it will be working correctly first.

This is the code of [the page where you can access the pop-up](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?133290). Here is the code inside the pop-up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hosted.musesradioplayer.com/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
MRP.insert({
'url':'localhost:8000/stream',
'lang':'es',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':65,
'autoplay':true,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio Ninguna',
'welcome':'Bienvenido a...',
'bgcolor':'#FFFFFF',
'skin':'radiovoz',
'width':220,
'height':69
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I set the code of the pop-up in the same page but in a redirect link and it works, but doesn't seem to work inside the pop-up, and that's what I need.

Comment: How are you opening the popup?

Comment: @PaulS. wow, that was fast, well i submit the code in a no-paste, you can check it out!, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the no-paste link I found the following:

```
window.open('localhost:8000/player/index.html','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300')
```

It should work if you add the protocol to the url like so:

```
window.open('http://localhost:8000/player/index.html','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300')
```

That way, the browser knows it's an absolute Url.

Comment: Man, You Rock!, you are totaly Right!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just had this similar issue and this solution worked for me as well!  This was driving me insane.  Thanks!